# Flutter snackbar is being called 4 times

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using flutter_bloc package and I have created an internet cubit which checks the internet connectivity and updates its state (**InternetConnected, InternetDisconnected and InternetLoading**). Below is the cubit

```
class InternetCubit extends Cubit<InternetState> {
  late Connectivity connectivity;
  late StreamSubscription internetConnectivitySubscription;
  InternetCubit(this.connectivity) : super(InternetLoading()) {
    internetConnectivityStream();
  }

// CHECK IF INTERNET IS CONNECTED OR DISCONNECTED
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> internetConnectivityStream() {
    return internetConnectivitySubscription =
        connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectivity) {
      if (connectivity == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
          connectivity == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        emitInternetConnected();
      } else {
        emitInternetDisconnected();
      }
    });
  }

  void emitInternetConnected() => emit(InternetConnected());

  void emitInternetDisconnected() => emit(InternetDisconnected());

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    internetConnectivitySubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

It works perfectly and updates the state using **StreamsSubscriptions**

I then created a global scaffold widget where I wrap all my Widgets in it `MainScaffold(child: routeWidget),`.

Inside the MainScaffold, I have a blocListener which listens to the state on my internet cubit and shows a snackbar with different content depending on the state.

```
import '../logic/internet_cubit/internet_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class MainScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScaffold({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocListener<InternetCubit, InternetState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is InternetConnected) {
            //
          } else if (state is InternetDisconnected) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                content: Text('Please check your internet connection'),
              ),
            );
          } 
        },
        listenWhen: (previous, current) {
          if (previous is InternetDisconnected &&
              current is InternetConnected) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                content: Text('We\'re back online'),
              ),
            );
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now everything works when I turn on and off my wifi but the scaffold is being called 4 times before it finally dissappears. I want it to show ones but I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: I do not see any error in the code at the moment. But i wouldn't show a snackbar in the listenWhen, just put the logic there when the BlocListener should react. You can show a snackbar in the first if  (state is InternetConnected). Which snack bars are displayed 4x? The one with We're back online oder the Please check your internet connection?

Comment: Yeah that is true. I just realized

Comment: What I would do: I would look where and how often your states are emitted. You can put some prints in your onConnectivityChanged and in your listener. emit is apparently called somewhere several times.

Comment: Okay so what I've realized is that the more I go deeper inside the routes, the more the snackbars are shown. The problem might be coming from the main scaffold.

Comment: I added print statements in the cubit and its emiting just ones. No problem there